# Define template erase() method for std::list

Tags: c++

Here, I want to define erase() method for std::list., I want to make sure that it is correct
I try the following:

```
         template<typename t> list<t>::unsigned erase(const T& E)
            {
                current= head;
                prcurrent=null;
                 while(current!=null & current->data!=E)
                 precurrent=current;
                 if current->data=E;
                   {
                      precurrent->link=current->link;
                      delete current;
                   }
               used--;
             }
```

Comment: ... and your question is?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it. Because you can not modify the header file of `std::list` (if you don't want change the standard).

You can wrap `std::list` with your custom class and export methods to it, then add your own methods.